# Is std::string an array of two iterators?

Tags: c++, string, std, braced-init-list

I do not understand the behavior of the following snippet.
How could this be happening?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string s = "apple";
  string foo = {s.begin(), s.end()};
  cout <<  foo << endl;
}
```

output:
`apple`

Comment: It's a constructor call.

Comment: It's the syntax for uniform initialization, introduced back in C++11. Here it's used to call [constructor 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string`. `foo` is a copy of `s`, change in one won't be reflected in another (which would be the case if `foo` only stored the iterators).

Comment: `foo` is list-initialized from the two iterators, which constructs a new string from said iterators. To answer your question in the question title: no.

Comment: Thanks for all your input.
I checked the constructor 6 link but it doesn't look like what I wrote here..
Or am I mistaken?
`
template< class InputIt >

basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
`

As far as I know, {} is meant for arrays.

Comment: @HeeHwang `{}` is for "uniform initialization" and can do all sorts of things to try to construct an object. For most class types, it will try to match the contents of `{}` with one of the type's constructors. For `std::string` it can be used to initialize the string like an array (ex. `std::string s { 'a', 'b', 'c'};`) but `s.begin()` and `s.end()` are not convertible to `char` so that constructor is ignored and another one is searched for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You nailed it. This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your advice. I should have been more careful when posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse how an object is *constructed* over what it fundamentally is.

A constructor can, and will, take in all kinds of things. Quite often these arguments are converted in some way, transformed into the form that's a more natural fit for the class in question.

In this case you're constructing a string out of a range of characters, or in other words, an arbitrary substring. There are many other methods, including converting from `char*`, which is something you'll see all the time:

```cpp
std::string example = "example";
```

Here you can read that as "`example` is *initialized with* the value `"example"`".

Comment: Got it. you certainly know where I got confused. Thank you.

Comment: A `std::string_view`, in contrast, _is_ just a pair of iterators. The difference is that a `std::string` makes a _copy_ of its data, while a `std::string_view` does not.